# Beautiful Soup specific td tag?

Tags: html, beautifulsoup, html-table

Here is the HTML code

```
<tr id="n1102">
    <td align="right" valign="top" style="width: 50px; text-align: left;">
        <a href="analects/xue-er/zh#n1102" class="popup" style="font-size: 12pt;">1</a>  
        <div style="display: inline-block; zoom: 1; *display: inline;'">
            <a href="dictionary.pl?if=gb&amp;id=1102" class="sprite-more" title="someText1" rel="nofollow">someText1
                <div style="display: inline;"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" style="white-space: nowrap; color: #777777;"  class="ctext opt">Text not want</td>
    <td class="ctext">
        <div id="comm1102"></div>THE WANTED TEXT
    </td>
</tr>
```

How to find **THE WANTED TEXT** or how to filter with requirement? The code below returns **Text not want**.

```
import bs4
root=bs4.BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
tds=root.find_all('td', {'class': 'ctext'})
print(tds)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the wanted text is always next to `<div>`, you can use CSS selector `td.ctext:has(> div)` (Find all `<td>` with `class="ctext"` that has **direct** children `<div>`):

For example(`txt` contains your HTML snippet from the question):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for td in soup.select('td.ctext:has(> div)'):
    print(td.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
THE WANTED TEXT
```

---

Or: You can select all `<div>` tags which `id=` begins with "comm..." and then find next text sibling:

```
for div in soup.select('div[id^="comm"]'):
    print(div.find_next_sibling(text=True).strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html =  """
<tr id="n1102">
    <td align="right" valign="top" style="width: 50px; text-align: left;">
        <a href="analects/xue-er/zh#n1102" class="popup" style="font-size: 12pt;">1</a>  
        <div style="display: inline-block; zoom: 1; *display: inline;'">
            <a href="dictionary.pl?if=gb&amp;id=1102" class="sprite-more" title="someText1" rel="nofollow">someText1
                <div style="display: inline;"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" style="white-space: nowrap; color: #777777;"  class="ctext opt">Text not want</td>
    <td class="ctext">
        <div id="comm1102"></div>THE WANTED TEXT
    </td>
</tr>
"""
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
print (doc.select('div#comm1102').nextText())
```

Result:

```
THE WANTED TEXT
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples